# Spring 3: How to call @Async annotated methods from the TaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous

I'm new to asynchronous task execution in Spring, so please forgive me if this sounds like a silly question.

I read that @Async annotation is introduced  from Spring 3.x onward at method level to invocation of that method will occur asynchronously.
I also read that we can configure the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor in the spring config file.

What I'm not able to understand is that how to call a @Async annotated method from a tak executor lets suppose - AsyncTaskExecutor

Earlier we used to do something like in a class:

```
@Autowired protected AsyncTaskExecutor executor;
```

And then

```
executor.submit(<Some Runnable or Callable task>)
```

I'm not able to understand the relationship between @Async annotated methods and TaskExecutor.

I tried searching a lot over the internet but could not get anything on this.

Can somebody provide an example for the same.

Answer (score 30):

Here's an example of `@Async` use:

```
@Async
void doSomething() {
    // this will be executed asynchronously
}
```

Now call that method from another class and it will run asynchronously. If you want a return value use a `Future`

```
@Async
Future<String> returnSomething(int i) {
    // this will be executed asynchronously
}
```

The relationship between `@Async` and `TaskExecutor` is that `@Async` uses a `TaskExecutor` behind the scenes. From the docs:

> By default when specifying @Async on a method, the executor that will be used is the one supplied to the 'annotation-driven' element as described above. However, the value attribute of the @Async annotation can be used when needing to indicate that an executor other than the default should be used when executing a given method.

So to set up a default executor, add this to your spring config

```
<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />
```

Or to use a particular executor for a single use try

```
@Async("otherExecutor")
```

See http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async

Comment: I read the documentation too but I don't quite understand how that relates to runnables? Do I need to mark something with Runnable and implement a run method or that's not needed?

Comment: You don't need to. Just mark the method that you want to run asynchronously with @Async and when you call it, it should run asynchronously.

Comment: @Planky This is great. But when I am doing the same using a void main and simplest spring application by getting bean as ApplicationContext = new ClassPathXml...(). and doing the async invocation. It is invoking method in separate thread, till this is fine. But the program is not exiting, I mean after execution of last line of main program is still alive. I tried to set keep-alive to 2 sec but in vain. I ran the program in run mode not in debug node. Any insight on this? If you want I can post the code in separate qstn.

Comment: @anirban I'm not sure. You might try isolating the problem specifically to whether or not you use the async annotation. I always run Spring apps as web apps so I don't expect them to stop running.

Comment: Thanks, actually I resolved the issue. I have to use pool-size in range, which sets allow time out to true. <task:executor id="ampsTaskExecutor" pool-size="0-2" keep-alive="2" rejection-policy = "CALLER_RUNS" queue-capacity = "1000"/>. Previously I were using pool as single integer.

Answer (score 5):

Complete Example

1. Config Spring

   ```
   @Configuration        
   @EnableAsync        
   @ComponentScan("com.async")
   public class AppConfig {

       @Bean
       public AsyncManager asyncManger() {
           return new AsyncManager();
       }

       @Bean
       public AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor() {
           return new AsyncExecutor();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Executor Class Created, Executor i have created so that spring takes care of thread management.

   ```
   public class AsyncExecutor extends AsyncConfigurerSupport {

       @Override
       public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
           ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
           executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
           executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
           executor.setQueueCapacity(500);
           executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Violation-");
           executor.initialize();
           return executor;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Create a manager.

   ```
   public class AsyncManager {

       @Autowired
       private AsyncService asyncService;

       public void doAsyncTask(){
           try {
               Map<Long, ViolationDetails> violation = asyncService.getViolation();
               if(!org.springframework.util.CollectionUtils.isEmpty(violation)){
                   violation.entrySet().forEach( violationEntry -> {System.out.println(violationEntry.getKey() +"" +violationEntry.getValue());});
               }
               System.out.println("do some async task");
           } catch (Exception e) {
           }

       }
   }
   ```
4. Configure your service class.

   ```
   @Service
   public class AsyncService {

       @Autowired
       private AsyncExecutor asyncExecutor;

       @Async
       public Map<Long,ViolationDetails> getViolation() {
           // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           List<Long> list = Arrays.asList(100l,200l,300l,400l,500l,600l,700l);
           Executor executor = asyncExecutor.getAsyncExecutor();
           Map<Long,ViolationDetails>  returnMap = new HashMap<>();
           for(Long estCode : list){
               ViolationDetails violationDetails = new ViolationDetails(estCode);
               returnMap.put(estCode, violationDetails);
               executor.execute((Runnable)new ViolationWorker(violationDetails));
           }
           return returnMap;       
       }
   }
   class ViolationWorker implements Runnable{

       private ViolationDetails violationDetails;

       public ViolationWorker(ViolationDetails violationDetails){
           this.violationDetails = violationDetails;
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           violationDetails.setViolation(System.currentTimeMillis());
           System.out.println(violationDetails.getEstablishmentID() + "    " + violationDetails.getViolation());
       }
   }
   ```
5. Model.

   ```
   public class ViolationDetails {
       private long establishmentID;
       private long violation;


       public ViolationDetails(long establishmentID){
           this.establishmentID = establishmentID;
       }

       public long getEstablishmentID() {
           return establishmentID;
       }
       public void setEstablishmentID(long establishmentID) {
           this.establishmentID = establishmentID;
       }
       public long getViolation() {
           return violation;
       }
       public void setViolation(long violation) {
           this.violation = violation;
       }

   }
   ```
6. Test to Run

   ```
   public class AppTest {
       public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
           AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
           ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
           ctx.refresh();

           AsyncManager task= ctx.getBean(AsyncManager.class);
           task.doAsyncTask();
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

In the config file, one should mention an annotation driven task with the thread pool name and method with @Async(pool name) will be executed as part of that pool. This creates a proxy class for the one which has @Async annotation and executes it for every thread.

Comment: it sound more like a comment, rather than an answer. Could you specify a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can add @Async on your method and the following to your Application context.

```
    <task:annotation-driven executor="asynExecutor"/>   
    <task:executor id="asynExecutor" pool-size="5" />
```