# How to return from a long-running procedure call in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to call an Oracle PL/SQL procedure from Spring. The procedure takes a lot of time so I would like it to be executed in the background (asynchronously) and briefly return from the DAO method and controller.
What is the most elegant method to return from a long-running procedure? I do not have to track its execution in the request which calls the procedure.

What currently I have is:

```
@Override
public void submitJob(final Integer param1, final String param2, final Integer param3) {
    jdbcTemplate.execute(
        new CallableStatementCreator() {
            public CallableStatement createCallableStatement(Connection con) throws SQLException{
                CallableStatement cs = con.prepareCall("{call PCKG.MY_PROC(?, NULL, ?, ?)}");
                cs.setInt(1, param1);
                cs.setString(2, param2);
                cs.setInt(3, param3);
                return cs;
            }
        },
        new CallableStatementCallback() {
            public Object doInCallableStatement(CallableStatement cs) throws SQLException{
                cs.execute();
                return null;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Put `@Async` on the `submitJob` method, register a `TaskExecutor` together with `<task:annotation-driven />` and you should be good to go. Check http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async

Answer (score 1):

You can add `@Async` on the `submitJob` method:

```
@Async
@Override
public void submitJob(final Integer param1, final String param2, final Integer param3) {
  jdbcTemplate.execute( ...
```

and the following to your Application context:

```
    <task:annotation-driven executor="asynExecutor"/>   
    <task:executor id="asynExecutor" pool-size="5" />
```

Check other similar questions:

- [Spring 3: How to call @Async annotated methods from the TaskExecutor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746372/spring-3-how-to-call-async-annotated-methods-from-the-taskexecutor)
- [Spring async method called from another async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898547/spring-async-method-called-from-another-async-method)