# Spring @Transactional doesn't work for an annotated method when called from within service class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

In below code , when *methodInner()* is called from within *methodOuter*, should be under transaction bounds. But it is not.
But when  *methodInner()* is called directly from *MyController* class , it is bound by transaction. Any explanations?

***This is controller class.***

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("abcService")
    private MyService serviceObj;

    public void anymethod() {
        // below call cause exception from methodInner as no transaction exists  
        serviceObj.methodOuter(); 
    }

}
```

***This is service class***.

```
@Service("abcService")
public class MyService {

    public void methodOuter() {
        methodInner();
    }

    @Transactional
    public void methodInner() {
    .....
    //does db operation.
    .....
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you added @EnableTransactionManagement to your configuration?

Comment: Works as expected as that is the way how proxies work, only external method calls (i.e calls INTO the object) are intercepted, calls from within the object aren't intercepted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24902434/2504224 Replace `@Async` with `@Transactional` and effectively you have your answer

Comment: @Ludwig Magnusson : No,i have not used  EnableTransactionManagement .But i have put <tx:annotation-driven/> in xml config files. I hope that is enough. Spring is able to execute other methods under transaction bounds. Only for this special case it is not working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spring uses Java proxies by default to wrap beans and implement annotated behavior. When doing calls within a service you bypass proxy and run method directly, so annotated behavior is not triggered.

Possible solutions:

1. Move all `@Transactional` code to separate service and always do calls to transactional methods from outside
2. Use AspectJ and weaving to trigger annotated behavior even within a service

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Transactional` to `methodOuter()` and it works.