# Spring Transaction (@Transaction) with Plain JDBC without JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate, spring-transactions

I have plain JDBC code which is doing transaction management using Connection Interface. I wanted to switch to Spring Transaction Management in small steps.

Firstly I want to provide `PlatformTransactionManager` for my datasource and annotate my class / methods with @Transaction and keep my other logic same ie. using connection / PreparedStatement etc.

All the examples, which I see use JdbcTemplate. I was wondering can Spring Transaction be used without JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Why? Just issue SQL transaction statements.

Comment: @K.Nicholas: My question is I still don't want to change my code which looks something like:
`try (PreparedStatement pstmt = ....createPreparedStatement(connection);
                ResultSet result = pstmt.executeQuery()) `
I just want the transaction handling to move to Spring Transaction using @Transaction annotation, so that I don't have to take care of explicilty rolling back or commiting transaction etc.

Comment: Comes with JDBC doesn't it.

Comment: @K.Nicholas: Pure JDBC is too verbose. I want to eventually use Spring Transaction / JPA etc...I want to take small steps like first changing the transaction management  with Spring transaction then may be to use jdbcTemplate followed by JPA etc.

Comment: don't bother, just wasting time.

Comment: @K.Nicholas: Hmm...But is it possible to use Spring Tx with plain JDBC without JdbcTemplate?

Comment: Why? Just issue SQL transaction statements.

Comment: @K.Nicholas: I appreciate your advice to stick with SQL statements but for my understanding I wanted to know, if it is possible or not technically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically it is possible to use `@Transactional` without `JdbcTemplate` . But if you try to do it , you will sooner or later find that you are re-inventing what the things that are already done by `JdbcTemplate`.

What `@Transactional` does is that before executing a `@Transactional` method , it will help you to get a JDBC `Connection` from the `DataSource` , and start a transaction on this `Connection` .The JDBC `Connection` will then stored in a `ThreadLocal`.

That means if you do it without `JdbcTemplate` , you have to manually get this `Connection` from that `ThreadLocal` such that you can create a JDBC `Statement` from it for executing your SQL. Not to mention you have to manually release the JDBC resources such  `Statement` , `ResultSet` etc. properly  by yourself which all of these things are already take care by `JdbcTemplate`.

But if you have already implemented these JDBC codes manually and just want to let `@Transactional` to handle the transaction , you could try to inject the `DataSource` to your bean and then use the following method to get the `Connection` for your JDBC codes use :

```java
    Connection connection = DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource);
```

Also checkout `JdbcTemplate#execute(ConnectionCallback<T> action)` , it is useful for migrating the existing JDBC codes that expects a JDBC `Connection` to work on to `JdbcTemplate`.

Comment: Thanks! I had one more question.... Can I wrap my datasource in TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy instrad of getting connection from DataSourceUtils?

Comment: should be okay as `TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy` as it it also in the type of `DataSource`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's possible. Adding a `@Transactional` annotation to your methods, [as long as they follow the correct procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26058340/3415090) *should* make your methods transactional. But as others have mentioned if you're in the process of updating your app you might as well ditch plain JDBC and move across to Spring JPA/JDBC (depending on which version of Spring you're using).