# ThreadPoolTaskExecutor spawning unwanted threads

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I have two Async methods that are configured to use the same TaskExecutor.

```
@Async("myExecutor") 
public void foo() {
    system.out.println("foo from: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
}


@Async // this should use the primary defaultExecutor
// try to bombard the single thread pool with bunch of requests
public void generateFoo() {
    while(true) {
        system.out.println("generateBar from: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        this.foo();
    }
}
```

I want the underlining threadpool of myExecutor to have a coresize and maxsize of 1 and queue incoming requests for the thread. I.e only one thread executing foo() runs at a time and all other calls to foo() waits for their turn. In my Spring configuration class, I have

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.test" })
@EnableAsync
@EnableScheduling
public class FooBarConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
@Qualifier("defaultExecutor")
public TaskExecutor defaultExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Bean
@Qualifier("myExecutor")
public TaskExecutor myExecutor() {

    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
    executor.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return executor;
    }
}
```

However, I'm seeing that foo() isn't always being executed from the same thread. If I call foo() via a @Scheduled task from another thread, it runs on "myExecutor-1" as expected. But if foo() is called via generateFoo(), it seems to be running in whatever generateFoo() runs from, ie:

```
foo from: defaultExecutor-1
foo from: myExecutor-1
foo from: defaultExecutor-1
foo from: defaultExecutor-1
foo from: defaultExecutor-1
```

If I get rid of generateFoo()'s @Async, foo() still runs on whatever thread generateFoo() is running on.

Am I using the wrong TaskExecutor for what I'm looking for or configuring it incorrectly?

*edit*
As state in my original post, not making generateFoo() an async method doesn't seem to do the trick, as someone suggested.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring async method called from another async method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24898547/spring-async-method-called-from-another-async-method)

Comment: But if I get rid of the @Async on generateFoo() I still seem to get the same problem

Comment: Why would you not have the same problem? That's not the suggestion, read the duplicate and the linked articles.