# Spring Boot: Update Operation in New Thread

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, groovy

I have customDao as below in my springboot app,

```
@Component
public class CustomDao {

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate

    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    def logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.class);
    @Autowired
    public CustomDao(JdbcTemplate template) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = template
    }


    public insertRecord(sql,params){
        //insert
    }

    public updateRecord(sql,params){
       //update
    }
}
```

And am trying to make only update operation asynchronously in a new Thread, I havent worked much on Threads, can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Check [this article](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) for gentle introduction what you could do with Spring's `@Async` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

You may modify your `updateRecord` method to this:

```
public void updateRecord(sql, params) {
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        //Your code to update here
    }
    t.start();
}
```

`Thread t = new Thread() {...}` will create a new thread to do the specified work and `t.start()` will run the thread in the background.

Comment: But he will also need the `ThreadLocal`s from the original thread. Spring stores there some important stuff. Also it is better to use some form of thread pool. The current approach will quickly become "expensive".

Comment: @zloster could you please provide your answer with Thread pool and ThreadLocals

Comment: @RanPaun See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33337838/25429) for the `ThreadLocal`s - depending on the code base you may or may not need them. About the ThreadPool: you specify [`@Async("customThreadPoolExecutor")`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-qualification) and [define the configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-task-namespace-executor) of the customTHreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: One other thing for the ThreadPool: you can specify the default executor for these `@Async` tasks: `<task:annotation-driven executor="myExecutor" />`. Credit goes to this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19144306/25429

Answer (score 1):

You should use @Async to handle asynchronous tasks into Spring. You can find an example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/).